# Combine 3 Unity3D projects into one

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

i have build 3 unity games in different project, each project contain 1 Scene : `Game1 Game2 Game3`.

all of the games uses almost the same scripts names but the code inside is different, now i want to export each scene to unity packege, create new project with 3 buttons and allow to user load each game with pressing.
the problem is that 40% of the scripts named the same, changing each one manually can become nightmare.

how should i handle this?

Comment: 1) back ups!!!! 2) try unity packaging to transfer stuff. 3) most likely renaming will be done for you. But its never good to use allot of same names

Comment: this is my first time using it so its kind a lesson for me, how do i packaging to transfer stuff

Comment: if unity can change scripts name for me it would be great. like :"ProjectName"+"_"+"ScriptName"+".cs"

Comment: Select your scwne fil in hierachy and right click on it. Export ad unity package.

Comment: but it wont rename my script that way

Comment: It will name duplicates just like windows will do with numbers. Further more it will be manual fussion

Comment: i guess you didnt understand my point.
i am trying to import 3 packages from 3 different project to a new single project